# How to write equation exactly like this?

Tags: equations, xetex, pdftex, overleaf

[image]

I need help, I tried using everything but couldn't make it exactly like this

Comment: Welcome in the LaTeX community. What do you have tried? Can you put your work please? Aesthetically, in my opinion, the image code is not done well.

Comment: Communicate to us so sincerely (you can make an edit) that we should create the code ourselves. It will certainly look better than the image you inserted.

Answer (score 5):

Relative to the expression you show in the screenshot in your query, the following solution is (a) tighter in the horizontal dimension and (b) less tight in the vertical dimension. The extensible arrows are also deliberately made longer than they are in your screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{mathtools}  % for '\xRightarrow' macro and 'alignedat*' env.
\usepackage{amssymb}    % for '\mathfrak' and '\mathbb' macros

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{alignedat}{4}
  & \mathrm{I}  &\qquad& 5x_2+6x_2=3 &\quad& 
    \xRightarrow{5\mathrm{I}-6\mathrm{II}} &\quad& x_1=3 \\
  & \mathrm{II} &&       4x_1+5x_2=2 &&      
    \xRightarrow{5\mathrm{II}-4\mathrm{I}} &&      x_2=-2
\end{alignedat}
\qquad \Longrightarrow
\mathfrak{S} = 
  \begin{Bmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix} 
    3 \\ -2 
    \end{pmatrix}
  \end{Bmatrix}
\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2
\]
\end{document}
```